# Symfony 2 fosuserbundle logout

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

here's my problem i have 2 pages : index page when i'm not connected and an index page when i'm connected so when i'm connected and i try to type the url path of  the index page when i'm not connected i find myself disconnected and on the page index when i'm not logged in
i'm using fosuserbundle and here's my access control

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

need help thanks

Comment: What do you mean "connected"?  Logged in perhaps?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it clear? Also, an effort on spelling and punctuation would be appreciated.